# Python: Add/update instance attribute of custom object in a set of objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to add an attribute to an instance which is in a set.
The set of objects of the class `Problem` is identified by attribue `uid` (that's why they are hashed and compared):

```
class Problem:
    allowed_keys = [
        'flag1',
        'a_list_of_objects'
    ]

    def __init__(self, uid, name, **kwargs):
        self.uid = uid
        self.name = name
        self.__dict__.update((k, v) for k, v in kwargs.iteritems() if k in self.allowed_keys)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and getattr(other, 'uid', None) == self.uid

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.uid)

    def __ne__(self, other):
         return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __repr__(self):
         return json.dumps(self.__dict__, sort_keys=True)
```

All instances of this problem are added to a set.

```
problem_set = set()

problem1 = Problem(uid="abc123", name="name1", flag1=True)
problem_set.add(problem1)

problem2 = Problem(uid="xyz789", name="name2", flag2=False)
problem_set.add(problem2)
```

Now if I want to update the object `problem1` with another attribute (it will never exist before), it just won't add the `a_list_of_objects` to the existing `problem1`

```
my_list = [{"a": "avalue", "b": "bvalue"}]
problem3 = Problem(uid="abc123", name="name1", a_list_of_objects=my_list

print list(problem_set)
# same list as before
```

What do I need to do in order to achieve this? Using `@property` and create getters and setters for each attribute of class `Problem`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not modifying the existing `problem1` instance. You are creating an entirely different instance `problem3` albeit equal to `problem1` going by your implementation of `__eq__`. Instances satisifying equality are not *merged* or *synced* in the way I think you expect. Instances of your class with the same `uid` and thus hash value can exist freely outside a *set* as independent objects. Trying to add one of both to a *set* will drop one, not *sync* them.

To modify `problem1` you should instead do:

```
problem1.a_list_of_objects = my_list
```

Or you could assign to a copy of `my_list` to avoid sharing the same list among instances:

```
import copy

problem1.a_list_of_objects = copy.deepcopy(my_list)
```

New attributes can be *bound* to an existing instance of your class.

Comment: How do I properly merge them then (based on the `uid`)? I need to merge multiple attributes to the instance if it's already there, or create a new one if not. The list should be shared among instances.

Comment: You need to iterate through the set and check if an instance with that `uid` already exists. If yes, update. If no, create a new one. You can also use `in` to test if an equal instance already exists, but that won't give you a reference to the instance. A set comprehension can be used with the `in` check - if the check passes, and a simple `set.add` if it fails.

Comment: Thanks. Your input made me rewrite the code so that the `Problem` instance creation happens as a last step when all values are decided. Much simpler.